# Make a textInput as codeinput in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I tried to allow the user to enter some R code in shiny to run it, and for user friendly I provided the return indent and shortcut function, but there is another problem with the reserved text, I don't want the user to delete it, I blocked it, but there is also the problem that when the user selects it, it can be replaced by a letter although it can't be deleted! Very annoying.

Sorry I'm not familiar with js, I'm an R user and this is the answer I'm exploring with AI

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is that the "df_new <- df %>% " readonly, meaning the user can only append it

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  verbatimTextOutput("print_df"),
  textAreaInput("myCode", "My code:", value = "df_new <- df %>% \n    "),
  verbatimTextOutput("print_df_new")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df <- data.frame(
    cola = c(1:3),
    colb = c(4:6),
    colc = c(7:9)
  )
  df_new <- NULL

  output$print_df <- renderPrint({
    df
  })
  output$print_df_new <- renderPrint({
    print(eval(parse(text = input$myCode)))
  })

  runjs(
    '$(document).ready(function() {
      var textArea = document.getElementById("myCode");
      textArea.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        var prefix = "df_new <- df %>% ";
        var currentValue = textArea.value;
        var start = textArea.selectionStart;
        var selectedText = currentValue.substring(0, start);

        // %>% shortcut
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.key === "M") {
          e.preventDefault();
          var newText = selectedText + " %>% " + currentValue.substring(start);
          textArea.value = newText;
        }

        if (e.key === "Enter") {
          e.preventDefault();
          var newText = selectedText + "\\n    " + currentValue.substring(start);
          textArea.value = newText;
        }

        if (e.key === "Backspace" || e.key === "Delete") {
          if (start <= prefix.length) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }

      });
    });'
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```